# Как использовать переменную из одного скрипта в другом

Tags: godot, gdscript

Допустим в скрипте x есть переменная a, которую я хочу задействовать в другом скрипте и вывести в отладчик с помощью принта. Как такое можно осуществить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

рассмотрим два случая.

1. скрипт привязан к ноде.
   в этом случае нам нужно сначала получить ссылку на ноду.
   `node = get_node('scene_tree/node')`
   затем уже через ноду получаем доступ к переменной.
   `x = node.variable`
2. скрипт не привязан к ноде (синглтон)
   напрямую обращаемся к скрипту через его имя и берём оттуда переменную.
   `x = singleton.variable`

Comment: Юху, спасибо большое!

Comment: обращайся, братец, я спец

Comment: А как делать на неконкретных нод. например у ноды player > weapons > spear, sword , bow..
У каждой свои переменные в var attack как делать для таких